# About the function monad

Tags: haskell, monads

I have some confusion with the function monad. The function monad is defined as follow:

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where
     return x = \_ -> x
     h >>= f = \w -> f (h w) w
```

I tried to play around with it by writing a binding operation:

```
( (*2) >>= (+10) ) 3 

(return 3) :: ((->) Int)
```

But it caused errors. And I also try to rewrite a function AddStuff into the binding operations.

```
addStuff = do
           a <- (*2)
           b <- (+10)
           return (a+b)
```

then convert this function into

```
addStuff' w = (*2)  w >>= (\a ->
              (+10) w >>= (\b ->
              return (a+b) ))
```

I check the type of the new function as see

```
addStuff :: (Monad m, Num (m b), Num b) => m b -> m b
```

Why is that? How can I fix that?

Comment: You shouldn't use `<pre>` tags to insert code - that way you won't get syntax highlighting. You should use four spaces of indentation or the "code" button from the editing toolbar.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In `addStuff'` you write `(*2) w` and `(+10) w`. Those are equivalent to `w*2` and `w+10` respectively. So `addStuff'` is equivalent to this:

```
addStuff' w = w*2 >>= \a ->
              w+10 >>= \b ->
              return (a+b)
```

Writing it this way should make it obvious that here the left operands to `>>=` are numbers, not functions. That's why the inferred type is telling you that your function only works for numbers that are monads.

When eliminating `do` notation the left operand to `>>=` should be exactly the same as the right operand of `<-`. Also eliminating `do` notation does not add any arguments to the function. So the correct rewriting would look like this:

```
addStuff' = (*2) >>= \a ->
            (+10) >>= \b ->
            return (a+b)
```

---

As to why your earlier pieces of code don't work:

```
( (*2) >>= (+10) ) 3
```

The operator `>>=` has type `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. For simplicity let's assume that all the numbers in this code have type `Int`, then your left operand has type `Int -> Int` or `m Int` if `m` is `(->) Int`. So for some type `b` the right operand should have type `Int -> ((->) Int) b` or, more readably, `Int -> Int -> b`. The type it actually has though is `Int -> Int`. Therefore your expression is ill-typed.

```
(return 3) :: ((->) Int)
```

`((->) Int)` has kind `* -> *` - the type of a value must have kind `*`.

Or to approach this differently: `return 3` has type `m Int` for some `m` (still assuming that all integer literals have type `Int` for simplicity). So if `m` is `((->) Int)`, the type of `return 3` will be `((->) Int) Int` or `Int -> Int`, not `((->) Int)`.

Comment: So, can you explain about ( (*2) >>= (+10) ) 3 and 

(return 3) :: ((->) Int)

Comment: @chipbk10 I've expanded my answer.

Comment: `( (*2) >>= (+10) ) 3` would work if the num class had an `instance Num b => Num (a -> b)` which was historically a problem, but is no longer.