# Behavior of reverse >>= (==)

Tags: haskell

A function for determine if a string is a palindrome can be implemented in a pointfree applicative manner via

```
pal1 = (==) <$> reverse <*> id
```

And here is a monadic version

```
reverse >>= (==)
```

How does the modadic version work with no explicit call to id? I attempted to view the poinful representation using pointful and get back the same function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430397/about-the-function-monad

Answer (score 8):

This works using the fact that `x -> y` can be regarded as a kind of "reader monad". If we were to say

```
type Reader r x = r -> x
```

then we have an instance of `Monad (Reader r)`. So we can see that

```
reverse :: [x] -> [x]
```

is actually

```
reverse :: Reader [x] [x]
```

Similarly,

```
(==) :: [x] -> [x] -> Bool
```

can be written as

```
(==) :: [x] -> Reader [x] Bool
```

Then `(>>=)` joins the two together.

So... We start with `reverse`, which is a `Reader` action that reads a list and returns a list. We then use `>>=` to pass that to `==`, which is a function that takes a list, and returns a `Reader [x] Bool`.

In short, the input list is duplicated by the action of `Reader`, which basically takes an input and passes it to *every* function in the chain. (That's what the reader monad *is*.)

I hope that made some kind of sense... It took *me* a while to figure out!

Comment: Oh, making a `Reader` type synonym like that really clarifies the explanation! That's a great idea. I'm totally going to steal it next time I need to talk about the monad instance for `((->) r)` because that syntax is way too confusing :P.

Answer (score 5):

Let's have a look at the Monad instance for `((->) r)`:

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where
    return = const
    f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
```

and then simply fill in your monadic code:

```
reverse >>= (==) = \r -> (==) (reverse r) r
```

which we can write in a more familiar way:

```
\r -> reverse r == r
```

Answer (score 4):

To add to other answers, here is another POV on this. Let's take a definition of bind via `fmap` and `join`:

```
m >>= act = join (fmap act m)
```

The expression `(==) <$> reverse` has type `Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool` and is equivalent to `fmap (==) reverse`. Now, we pass it to `join :: m (m a) -> m a` and for `(->) r` monad instance the type would be `([a] -> [a] -> Bool) -> ([a] -> Bool)`. That is, join is exactly `<*> id` part.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to understand this is by looking at the types:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

specialized to the `((->) r)` instance:

```
(>>=) :: (r -> a) -> (a -> r -> b) -> r -> b
```

You are not given an `a`. The only way to produce one is to apply the first function `r -> a` to the `r` you are given. The only way to produce a `b` is to apply the second function to the `r` and the `a` you just produced. This means the only possible definition for this function<sup>*</sup> is:

```
f >>= g = \a -> g (f a) a
```

Plugging our arguments in, we get:

```
reverse >>= (==) 

-- definition of (>>=)
= \a -> (==) (reverse a) a

-- prefix to infix
= \a -> reverse a == a
```

Parametricity is a powerful tool for reasoning about polymorphic functions.

---

* other than bottom

Answer (score 1):

The other answers confirm that the two behave the same, but don't explain where the `id` actually *went*. In this answer, I will attempt to do so. The punchline is that, for Reader, we have a curious `id`-removing equation: `id >>= return . f = f`. (A more beautiful form of this equation is that `(id >>=) = (>>= id)`; together with the monad laws the beautiful form implies the easily-usable form.) To make the explanation a bit simpler, instead of trying to convert from applicative form to monadic form, I will just take it for granted that you believe the following equation:

```
(==) <$> reverse <*> id
= { too annoying to do carefully }
reverse >>= \xs -> id >>= \ys -> return ((==) xs ys)
```

So we will start from that last line, and end at `reverse >>= (==)`. Along the way, it will be key to observe that `id` is the identity for `(.)` -- which just so happens to be `fmap` for the Reader monad. Here we go:

```
reverse >>= \xs -> id >>= \ys -> return ((==) xs ys)
= { monad law }
reverse >>= \xs -> fmap ((==) xs) id
= { definition of fmap for Reader }
reverse >>= \xs -> (.) ((==) xs) id
= { id is the identity of fmap }
reverse >>= \xs -> (==) xs
= { eta reduction }
reverse >>= (==)
```

So what is the meaning of `id >>= return . f = f`? Well, treating functions as "indexed values", we can understand `id` as being the value that equals its index; and `return` as being the value that is the same everywhere. So `id >>= return . f` says "look at index `x`; then, (still at index `x`), return the value that ignores its index and has value `f x`". It just so happens that the index we ignore and the value we hand to `f` match up -- so we might as well skip all that indirection and simply say "look at index `x` and apply `f` to it". This is the meaning of the equation.